# Create S/MIME certificates

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate, mime, smime

I am trying to generate S/MIME certificate using the solution provided here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/103263/can-i-create-my-own-s-mime-certificate-for-email-encryption
Solution:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out smime.key 4096
openssl req -new -key smime.key -out smime.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in smime.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 1 -out smime.crt -setalias "Self Signed SMIME" -addtrust emailProtection -addreject clientAuth -addreject serverAuth -trustout
openssl pkcs12 -export -in smime.crt -inkey smime.key -out smime.p12
```

I want to provide credentials for signing mime data too. How can I possibly do that?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already created the credentials for signing MIME in you first three commands. You can sign some `text_to_sign.txt` file with your `smime.key` and `smime.crt`:

```
openssl smime -sign -in text_to_sign.txt -inkey smime.key -signer smime.crt
```